# error: pathspec 'tut51.cpp' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

i have a file named **tut51.cpp** i have already commited it before and pushed it to my github, but by mistakenly i have made changes to my file.

And now my file is in  modified status, how can i reverse the modified changes,
[image]

I tried git checkout but it shows me error.
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy the text directly out of your console instead.

Comment: Git says it is untracked. You must have gone to a branch or revision where the file was not yet added to the repo?

Comment: An *untracked file* is one that is in your working tree, but not in Git's index / staging-area. That indicates that this version of the file *is not* in Git. (Just because you can see it and work with it, does not mean it is *in Git*, since your working tree files are not in Git.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file is shown as untracked, it means that it is not included in the latest master branch on your remove server.  This could have happened for a few reasons:

1. When you made the prior commit that included `tut51.cpp`, it was not staged and did not get pushed to the server.  If this is the case, `tut51.cpp` may or may not have changed since the time that you intended to commit it.  There would be no way of knowing in this case and whatever you have now is all that you will have.  If you want to push this file to the repository then you will need to use `git add` then create a new commit.
2. File `tut51.cpp` was included in the master branch on the remote server previously, but has since been removed.  In this case you may have made changes to `tut51.cpp` and pulled from the server where the latest commit did not include `tut51.cpp`.  In this case the file would likely be left in place and unstaged to prevent eliminating your modifications.  If this is the case and `tut51.cpp` is no longer needed, then the problem can be resolved by deleting the file, but first be sure that it is not needed.